# Flying company delayed luggages on professional mission

Tags: air-travel, luggage, delays

I was on a professional mission for 5 days.
The flying company that I used, for reasons that I don't know, delayed (or lost for sometime) my luggages until the last day of my mission. 
That put me in trouble staying with the same clothes for 5 days, all my papers, PC, everything I needed for my mission was there.

When the company finaly found my luggages it didn't take the pain to apologize.

Will a law suit be successful?

Comment: I must be a weird guy. First time I took an intercontinental flight, on a holiday I didn't want to mess up, it came to me **natural** to put the most important and needed things in the hand luggage, so that in case something bad happened to my luggage I still had enough for a basic and it'd have been just a matter to replace clothes. And you go on a 5 days professional mission and you put everything critical in someone else hands? In the checked in luggage? Are you serious? You did put **all your papers and your PC** in the worst place ever in which you could put them in? O_O

Comment: Even though your core point is right, @motoDrizzt, I don't think there's a need to take quite that tone.

Comment: Luggage delays happen.  Don't pack anything critical in checked baggage if you can help it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you sue the airline for your delayed bags? Not unless the baggage is lost for thirty days.

Usually the airline will be willing to reimburse you for any essentials you needed to purchase, but this only extends to clothing and toiletries products. Keep your receipts. But you're not going to get a new laptop to use while your old one is delayed.

As you are travelling on business I imagine your employer will have a travel insurance scheme which may pay out some fixed amount for your delayed bags. This may be easier than dealing with the airline.

Although it's too late now, generally speaking, don't put anything in the hold that you are not prepared to lose. Many business travellers are hand-luggage-only for precisely this reason.